# When is an initial algebra isomorphic to an infinite coproduct?

Tags: category-theory

In the usual construction of initial algebras, we start with an initial object $0$ and the unique morphism $! : 0 \to F0$, iteratively constructing the morphisms $F^n! : F^{n-1}0 \to F^n0$ to construct the following diagram: $$ 0 \to F0 \to F^20 \to F^30 \to \dots $$ And if $F$ preserves $\omega$-colimits, then Adámek's theorem tells us that the colimit of this diagram is an initial algebra for $F$.

Intuitively speaking, from what I've garnered by looking at specific examples, the $F^n!$ maps seem to be acting as inclusions from the "less complete" representations of the data type (just to think about things in computer science-y terms for intuition's sake) to the "more complete" representations.

For instance, for the functor $F(X) = 1 + 2 \times X$, whose initial algebra gives us the type of binary lists, if we work out the graphs of the $F^n!$ maps in terms of intuitive binary list notation, we find:

$$F!([]) = [], F^2!([]) = [], F^2!([0]) = [0], F^2!([1]) = [1]$$

where in my computer science-y abuse of notation: $$ F0 = \{[]\}, F^20 = \{[],[0],[1]\}, F^30 = \{ [],[0],[1],[0,0],[0,1],[1,0],[1,1] \}, \dots $$

Of course, I'm glossing over the details here, but hopefully I've made my point about what the $F^n!$ maps intuitively represent. Thus, a cocone over this diagram is simply an object $X$ with injections $i_k : F^k0 \to X$ which commute with the inclusions $F^n!$. So, in other words, we simply require that the inclusions $i_k$ from the partial data structures $F^n0$ to the completed data structure $X$ and the inclusions from the partial data structures to each other $F^n!$ are compatible.

However, many initial algebras have a simpler representation. For instance, $\mathbb{N} \cong 1 + 1 + 1 + \dots$, i.e. the infinite coproduct of $1$ with itself, instead of as the initial algebra of the endofunctor $F(X) = X + 1$. Or, to go back to my binary list example, it seems like we should also be able to construct the initial algebra of the endofunctor $F(X) = 1 + 2 \times X$ as the infinite coproduct $1 + 2 + 2 \times 2 + 2\times 2 \times 2 + \dots$.

So, my question is, when is this possible in general? I'd expect that this probably holds in general for polynomial endofunctors, but does it hold for any other important classes of endofunctors? Are there any examples of endofunctors $F$ which cannot be constructed as an infinite coproduct, and have to be constructed as the colimit of some chain?

Comment: a suggestion for those who want stack exchange as a reference place (it's pretty old question already): shortening the question and adding references